# R time series bar plot grouped by month

Tags: r

I have a data frame of monthly river flow data from 1936 - 2022 that looks like this:

```
month   average_discharge
   <chr>               <dbl>
 1 1936-01             2882.
 2 1936-02             2133.
 3 1936-03             1519.
 4 1936-04             1214.
 5 1936-05             7314.
 6 1936-06            63723.
 7 1936-07            37923.
 8 1936-08            23303.
```

Using this data I am trying to recreate the attached graph so each bar is the monthly data and it's grouped by month. Any ideas how I can achieve that in R? I've had a look around but can't find anything similar.

[image: River data bar chart]

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Using the reproducible data `DF` in the Note at the end and since the data starts in January we can use `monthplot` as shown in the code below.

```
monthplot(DF$discharge, ylab = "discharge", col = "blue")
```

(continued after image)
[image: screenshot]

**2)** If the series does not start in January then the above will result in misalignment so convert to ts first using `tser` in place of DF$discharge.  This also adds 3 character month labels and a grid.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = as.yearmon)
tser <- as.ts(z)

monthplot(tser, labels = month.abb, ylab = "discharge", 
 col = "blue", tck = 0)
x.grid <- 0.55 + 0:12
y.grid <- pretty(DF$discharge)
abline(v = x.grid, h = y.grid, col = adjustcolor("grey", alpha = 0.7))
axis(1, at = x.grid, lab = rep("", 13), tck = -0.02)
axis(2, at = y.grid)
```

(continued after image)

[image: screenshot]

**3)** Using ggplot2 and the forecast package:

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

ggmonthplot(tser) +
  aes(col = I("blue")) +
  ylab("discharge")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

Test input

```
set.seed(123)
tt <- seq(as.Date("1936-01-01"), as.Date("2022-12-31"), by = "month")
DF <- data.frame(month = format(tt, "%Y-%m"), 
  discharge = rnorm(length(tt))^2)
```

### Update

Added (2) and (3) and made various improvements.